# Sql return group of records till bit is true for all records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a group of records that update over time and I want them to be return until all of the records have one of the columns, a bit column true.

schema

```
| ID | BatchID | Value | SampleCompleted |
|  1 |  4444   | 3     |       1         |
|  2 |  4444   | 5     |       1         |
|  3 |  4444   | 20    |       1         |
|  4 |  4444   | 50    |       1         |
|  5 |  4444   | NULL  |     NULL        |
```

So in the example above I want to return all of those record returned until record 5 has been update with the SampleCompleted bit to 1. All of the records that are grouped will have the same batch ID. I know this is probably simple but I'm having a hard time figuring out the logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE BatchID IN
(
    SELECT BatchID FROM MyTable
    WHERE SampleCompleted IS NULL
)
```

Comment: I think you mean BatchID instead of ID.

Comment: Thank you, I was having a brain fart. I appreciate it!

Comment: Or just `SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE SampleCompleted IS NULL`? Or rahter `WHERE SampleCompleted=1` However, is there really any need for the sub-select?

Comment: The sub-select is needed to return the entire set of records for the batch.  The OP wants to see the entire batch when any or all batch records have a NULL value.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but `WHERE BatchID IN(...)` should be quite the same as if you've put the `WHERE` under the `SELECT` directly

Comment: The sub-select finds the BatchID, so in this case 4444, because it has a record with a NULL value.  The outer select now gets all records with BatchID of 4444, including the ones with SampleCompleted = 1.  If you have a single select using `WHERE SampleCompleted = 1`, you will only get the first 4 records, not all 5.

Comment: @PhillipXT, Ah, yes, see what you mean... Haven't read the question correctly. Might be, that `EXISTS` is faster, but this is a good solution: +1